# page method on several pages

Tags: asp.net

What's the best way to make several page methods available on multiple pages. All the pages that will contain these page methods belong to the same master page. Do I put them in the master page or do I create a base page?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should more specific. What these methods do?

Comment: The simpliest is that what you've already mentioned: add them to the MasterPage and call `((MyMaster)Page.Master).MyMethod`/`DirectCast(Page.Master, MyMaster).MyMethod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly more in-depth description of what the methods do might help, but depending on their purpose you have two options:

1. Create a base page class and allow the pages to inherit from that class (better option to use if the methods modify the page's internal state).
2. Create a library of static helper methods (better option if the methods are utility methods that don't modify the internal state of the page).

Comment: What do you mean by "modify the internal state of the page"? The page methods essentially take json inputs and return json outputs to the page.

Comment: @frenchie - If the methods modify variables that are private to the page.